# Правильное склонение

Tags: склонение, орфоэпия

Как правильно: "в постЕ" или "в постУ"?

(Пост- сообщение на форуме) "В постЕ была допущена ошибка или в постУ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Это изъяснительный, а не местный падеж: "в чем", а не "где"."  А по-моему как раз "где".
-Где?
-В посту   ("в лесу" и устар. в песне "в темном лесе, в темном лесе...")
Мне кажется, что допустимы обе формы, хотя мне больше нравится "в посте"

Comment: Мы можем сказать: в письме (в чем и где), но не можем сказать: в лесу/лесе (в чем), только (где). Различаются значения "внутри предмета" и то значение, когда с помощью предмета обозначено место действия.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно писать "в посте". Это изъяснительный, а не местный падеж: "в чем", а не "где".

Comment: Эмм, сегодня получил противоположный ответ. Объяснялось тем, что "В посте" относится к православным традициям (Великий Пост), а "в посту" - к форумным сообщениям. То есть окончание определяется смысловым значением слова.

Comment: По-моему, в Интернете пишут обычно "в посте", например:
Что нельзя писать в посте:
1. Не допускается использование нецензурных и оскорбительных слов и выражений. И т.д.

Answer (score 2):

> Объяснялось тем, что "В посте" относится к православным традициям (Великий Пост),

Да. Не обязатльно православным, кстати. Мусульмане, например, тоже по-своему постятся.

> а "в посту" - к форумным сообщениям.

Нет. "На/в посту" - только к значению *дежурство; место для выполнения обязанностей по наблюдению, охране, досмотру*: на боевом посту, стоять на посту.

Слово "пост" в значении *сообщение, заметка (в газете, на стенде, в Интернете)* = это еще одно, новое значение. На него формы склонения предыдущего значения не распространяются.

(+) 28.12.2013

[[@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)

> Никогда не слышала ни "в постЕ", ни "в посту", только - "во время поста"

Очень трудно найти безусловный местный падеж для слова пост. Но обычный предложный вполне возможен во фразах типа: "в посте главное [не воздержание, а молитва]" (гуглятся тысячами).
"В посте" в значении "во время поста" передается падежом винительным: "в пост надо молиться".

Возможно, кстати,  именно отсутствие необходимости в местном падеже и стало одной из причин того, что словари отказывают слову пост (воздержание) в праве на форму "в посту", хотя, думается, вопрос глубже - в этимологии слова.

Comment: А можно привести примеры с предлогом "В ПОСТУ" во всех значениях.

Comment: А  ударение  разве  не  различное:  в  пОсте  и  в  постЕ.  Можно  и  без  обращения  к  религиозным  традициям   обойтись.

Comment: >А можно привести примеры с предлогом "В ПОСТУ" во всех значениях.  
  
Не совсем понял... "В посту" возможно только в одном значении. да и то в несколько натянутом контексте: "в посту

Comment: >А ударение разве не различное: в пОсте и в постЕ. Можно и без  обращения к религиозным традициям обойтись.    
  
Вы меня тоже озадачили. А в каком значении вы предлагаете "в пОсте"? Если в смысле "заметка, сообщение", то возможно, ибо слово не фиксируется. Но никогда подобного не слушал. Только "в постЕ". Во всех других значениях ударение строго на флексии.

Answer (score 2):

Если  это  текст  в  блоге,  то  в  пОсте.  Если  это  религиозный  пост,  то  в  постЕ.  "Монаху  подобает  в  келии  сидети,  во  постЕ  молитися,  нищету  терпети."  (Симеон  Полоцкий).

Comment: Пост (в 3-ем значении) в словарях еще не значится. Надо думать, что он будет относиться к акцентному классу А, когда ударение во всех формах падает на основу. Тогда пост-сообщение будет противопоставлен другим значениям слова.
Кстати, в словаре дается значение (религ.)в посту (во время поста) - может быть, оно заменяет прежнее "в посте"?

Comment: Cловарь  ударений  и  произношения ( 1959 г.) в  отношении  религиозного  поста  даёт  обе  формы -  в  посту  и  в  посте.  Но  в  том  и  другом  случае  ударение  падает  на  последний  слог.

Comment: У меня пара относительно новых словарей (2009 и 2010 год) - там уже только "в постУ".

Comment: Тенденция  ясна.  Но  я  в  своём  ответе  акцент  делаю  на  ударении - разное  ударение  указывает  на  разные  слова,  т.е.  омонимы.

Comment: Никогда не слышала ни "в постЕ", ни "в посту", только - "во время поста"

Comment: Я  тоже  не  слышал  -  я  в  словаре  посмотрел.

Comment: >Никогда не слышала ни "в постЕ", ни "в посту", только - "во время поста"  

В текст своего ответа добавил.

Comment: В  посте  и  молитве...  В  посте  -  это  постясь,  у  выражения  "во  время  поста"  значение  более  широкое.

Comment: behemothus, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

"В посту" (=в сообщении) - это диалектизм какой-то дремучий. Не говорите так.
Бывает "в пост"(когда, религ.) и "на посту"(на службе). Остальное - извращения. да, про интернет: в посте.

Comment: А  ударение  где ?

Comment: Об этом писали выше, и я совершенно согласна с Софией: "...Надо думать, что он будет относиться к акцентному классу А, когда ударение во всех формах падает на основу".
Но пока распространено ударение "в постЕ", что само по себе звучит просторечно. Что до меня, я вообще не пользуюсь  этим англицизмом "пост" и его производными "постить", "запостить". Предпочитаю "сообщение" или "текст" и "написать". 
Во фразе "я написал пост в блог" слово "пост" просто лишнее, вам не кажется?